# Onclick open and close div error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am creating a web services which generates array. I want div open and close on this. I have a div which is on clicking should open another div but in my case when i load my page all divs are opened by default. All i want div to be remained close only on clicking it should open. I want on click of `class="innr-spl3 kmore"`, `ul class="details"` to be opened and again on clicking it should close.

PHP

```
      <?php if(count($json['resultList']) > 0): ?>
      <?php 
        foreach ($json['resultList'] as $key=>$value) {
            if($json["resultList"][$key]["interestRateMin"] == $json["resultList"][$key]["interestRateMax"]){
                $interest = $json["resultList"][$key]["interestRateMin"];
            }
            else{
                $interest = $json["resultList"][$key]["interestRateMin"].' - '.$json["resultList"][$key]["interestRateMax"];

}

            if($json["resultList"][$key]["financingPercentageMin"] == $json["resultList"][$key]["financingPercentageMax"]){
                $financing = $json["resultList"][$key]["financingPercentageMin"];
            }
            else{
                $financing = $json["resultList"][$key]["financingPercentageMin"].' - '.$json["resultList"][$key]["financingPercentageMax"];

}

                echo '
  <div class="cr-content">                
                <div class="bank-rates">
      <ul>
   <li>
   <div class="innr-spl" style="padding: 5px 0;">
          <span style="display:block;"><img src="'.$json["resultList"][$key]["imageUrl"].'"></span>
   <span class="hide">'.$json["resultList"][$key]["bankName"].'</span>
   </div>
   </li>

 <li><div class="innr-spl2">' . $interest . '%' . '</div></li>
 <li><div class="innr-spl2">' . $financing  . '</div></li>
   <li class="hide"><div class="innr-spl3 kmore" id="'.$key.'"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>View Datails</div> </li>  
      </ul>
      <div style="clear:both"></div>

      <ul class="details" id="ban_'.$key.'">
        <li><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" aria-hidden="true"></i> Maximum Loan Amount : '.$json["resultList"][$key]["maxLoanAmt"].'</li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" aria-hidden="true"></i> Max Tenure (In Years) : '.$json["resultList"][$key]["repaymentTenureInYears"].'</li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" aria-hidden="true"></i> Interest Rate Type : '.$json["resultList"][$key]["rateType"].'</li>    
      </ul>

    </div>
    </div>

                ';
                $i++;
        }

    ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.kmore').click(function(){
        var name = this.id;
        //alert(name);
        $("#ban_" + name).slideToggle("fast");
    });

});
```

Comment: 1.`<ul class="details" id="ban_'.$key.'" style = "display:none;">`.2 `var name = $(this).attr('id');`

Comment: @Anant yes it worked. need to add display none.. thank you

Comment: @user6924814 You use `.hide()` in Jquery to hide all the elements by default.

Comment: @user6924814  glad to help you. cheers :):)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things needed in your case:-

1. `<ul class="details" id="ban_'.$key.'" style = "display:none;">`
2. `var name = $(this).attr('id'); // use attr()`

Note:- rest of the code seems fine to me.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.attr()` to get the the id

And `hide()` your `ul.details` by default when page gets ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.details').hide();
    $('.kmore').click(function(){
         var name = $(this).attr('id');
         //alert(name);
         $("#ban_" + name).toggle();
    });
});
```

Please make sure that your getting right element with proper id by using `console.log()`